# Hard linear-gradients (e.g. triangles) look jagged or blurry (Chrome vs IE)

Tags: css

I'm building my content-triangles with linear-greadients. Why? Because I need them with a responsive width (not possible with fixed deg-rotation hacks etc.) but when it comes to cross browser testing IE and Chrome look different - I guess chrome has some antialiasing/interpolation missing here.

```css
.box {
  width: 100%;
  color: white;
  background: darkgreen;
  padding: 20px;
  position: relative;
  text-align:center;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}
.box:before, .box:after, .box--darkorange:before, .box--darkorange:after {
      content: "";
   position: absolute;
   width: 50%;
   left: 0;
   bottom: -30px;
   height: 30px;
   display: block;
   background: linear-gradient(to right top, transparent 50%, darkgreen 50%);
}
.box:after {
      left: 50%;
   background: linear-gradient(to left top, transparent 50%, darkgreen 50%);
}

.box--darkorange {
  background: darkorange;
}
.box--darkorange:before {
   background: linear-gradient(to right top, transparent 49%, darkorange 50%);
}
.box--darkorange:after {
      left: 50%;
   background: linear-gradient(to left top, transparent 49%, darkorange 50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
The triangle looks jagged in Chrome but good in IE 10+ :-(
</div>

<div class="box box--darkorange">
The triangle below looks good in Chrome but horrible blurred in IE :-(
</div>
```

And here is an image of what I mean:
[Jagged triangle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ujxAE.jpg)

And here is my fiddler: https://jsfiddle.net/mnnhvgxz/

EDIT: Oh, and sure I could mess around with the values like 49.5 to 50 or so which would look nearly good in both worlds but maybe you guys no a besser solution or why IE is such blurry on this one or how to AA it in Chrome. Thanks!

Comment: I know it is not a solution to your problem, but you can simply use modernizr  to detect IE browser and then just apply the appropriate style.

Answer (score -1):

when you have use gradient then you have to remember those things because your code will be run on different platform.

```
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(red,yellow,blue); /* Safari 5.1-6.0 */
background: -o-linear-gradient(red,yellow,blue); /* Opera 11.1-12.0 */ 
background: -moz-linear-gradient(red,yellow,blue); /* Firefox 3.6-15 */
background: linear-gradient(red,yellow,blue); /* Standard syntax */
```